# How to get the difference of dates inside a data.table

Tags: r, data.table

The data.table looks like this

```
              AccId  Balance BusinessDate flag_change
             (fctr)    (dbl)       (fctr)       (dbl)
1  00000252-MMM-140 23550.85   2012-04-30           1
2  00000252-MMM-140 23567.20   2012-05-31           1
3  00000252-MMM-140 23579.49   2012-06-30           1
4  00000252-MMM-140 23591.20   2012-07-31           1
5  00000252-MMM-140 23603.89   2012-08-31           1
6  00000252-MMM-140 23629.67   2012-09-30           1
7  00000252-MMM-140 23642.15   2012-10-31           1
8  00000252-MMM-140 23642.15   2012-11-30           0
9  00000252-MMM-140 23652.26   2012-12-31           1
10 00000252-MMM-140 23652.26   2013-01-01           0
```

Now I want to calculate the dates where the balance has been changed for the accounts. What I ideally need is a column consisting of the date difference of each `BusinessDate` for the change in balance per `accID`and if its not changed in next `BusinessDate` like below it would have 0 and the it would go to the next business date and calculate the difference. In the below example I would like to have

```
1  00000252-MMM-140 23550.85   2012-04-30           1    1
2  00000252-MMM-140 23567.20   2012-05-31           1   31
3  00000252-MMM-140 23579.49   2012-06-30           1   30
4  00000252-MMM-140 23591.20   2012-07-31           1   31
5  00000252-MMM-140 23603.89   2012-08-31           1   31
6  00000252-MMM-140 23629.67   2012-09-30           1   30
7  00000252-MMM-140 23642.15   2012-10-31           1   31
8  00000252-MMM-140 23642.15   2012-11-30           0    0
9  00000252-MMM-140 23652.26   2012-12-31           1   61
```

However I can not figure out how to achieve this.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

We can convert the 'data.frame' to 'data.table', change the 'BusinessDate' to `Date` class.  Get the difference between adjacent 'BusinessDate' with `diff` that have 'flag_change` not equal to 0.

```
library(data.table)
setDT(df1)[, BusinessDate:= as.Date(BusinessDate)]
df1[flag_change!=0, Diff:= c(1,diff(BusinessDate)), by =  AccId]
head(df1,-1)
#              AccId  Balance BusinessDate flag_change Diff
# 1: 00000252-MMM-140 23550.85   2012-04-30           1    1
# 2: 00000252-MMM-140 23567.20   2012-05-31           1   31
# 3: 00000252-MMM-140 23579.49   2012-06-30           1   30
# 4: 00000252-MMM-140 23591.20   2012-07-31           1   31
# 5: 00000252-MMM-140 23603.89   2012-08-31           1   31
# 6: 00000252-MMM-140 23629.67   2012-09-30           1   30
# 7: 00000252-MMM-140 23642.15   2012-10-31           1   31
# 8: 00000252-MMM-140 23642.15   2012-11-30           0   NA
# 9: 00000252-MMM-140 23652.26   2012-12-31           1   61
```

EDIT: Added `by = AccId` based on @K.Rohde's comments.

Comment: By adding a `by = "AccId"` you can do this for each individual `AccId` value. (Otherwise there will be overlap problems when `AccId` changes.)

Comment: What I mean is `df1[flag_change!=0, Diff:= c(1,diff(BusinessDate)), by = "AccId"]`

Comment: @K.Rohde  Thanks for the comment.  Yes, it should be the case.